# How to run an inline-function twice?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, pubnub

I'm using Gametime.js to make a world chat in real time.

Messages are stored in a database.

Gametime.js uses PubNub and for some reason PubNub needs the message sent twice so it actually does it.

How can I make a function run twice?

I've tried this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { gametime.run("msg", [msg]) }
```

And it works, it's just that I do this very often in my script, so is there a way to do it without a for/while loop?

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```js
// inline code, cannot run for loop right here
function example(msg) { doSomething(), doSomethingElse, {{run twice}}, done() }
```

Comment: Figure out why you need to send the message twice, instead of trying to fix around the actual problem.

Comment: There should be no reason to run the function twice for any PubNub purposes. Curious to understand the actual issue.

Comment: I don't see any PubNub APIs in your code snippet. Can you share the PubNub code?

Comment: @CraigConover The Gametime.js uses PubNub built in. In the console (on any of my games or chat rooms) It will give me an error in between messages: `Error: PubNub call failed. Check status for details`. It doesn't matter when the seperation is 12 hours or 1 second it just doesn't send it twice. That's why I need to run it twice so I can make sure the other person can actually get the message. For debug purposes the script is right [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Parking-Master/Gametime.js-2.0@latest/gametime.js).

Comment: Cool, can't provide any insights but this isn't normal or expected. Definitely something on the client side. If you [enable PN SDK logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/troubleshooting) and reproduce and send it to [PN Support](support@pubnub.com), we can likely figure it out (it's free and we'd be motivated to know what is causing this - can bet money it isn't PN SDK or network and just something subtle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another function which will run your function twice, like this:

```js
function twice (callback) {
  callback();
  callback();
}

twice(() => console.log('hello'));
```

However, if you're experiencing a scenario where you are having to invoke a function twice to get the desired result, it sounds like there's another problem somewhere (in some code that you didn't show).

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting the run method, sounds like calling the method twice is a bug and this will make it easy to back out if it gets fixed.

```
gametime.oldRun = gametime.run;

gametime.run = (...params) => {
  this.oldRun(...params);
  this.oldRun(...params);
};
```

It could cause problems if internal methods call run so you could create run2

```
gametime.run2 = (...params) => {
  this.run(...params);
  this.run(...params);
};
```

Still easy to back out with a find and replace.